# Trying to display a static message and a string at the same time android

Tags: android

So I'm trying to make a simple app that takes your name from a TextField an after pressing the button it display something like Hello -string- (in our case the name). Thing is I've managed to get the actions between the text fields and the buttons done. My problem is I don't know how to make the display TextBot to show both the static message and the string at the same time.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user taps the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    displayMessage(message);
}

public void displayMessage(String message)
{
    TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

Comment: `textView.setText("Hello " + message)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void displayMessage(String message)
{
TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
textView.setText("Hello" + message);
}
```